# php string to int issue

Tags: php, wordpress, casting

I got a strange issue on PHP, i'm trying to cast a string to integer and got as result an empty int variable...

The variable is originally a string extracted from Visual Composer template variable.

```
<?php

var_dump($sec_id);
$sec_id = (int)$sec_id;
var_dump($sec_id);

?>
```

Here is the output:

[image: strange_issue]

Do I forget something?

Comment: I think you should create a new variable to pass the converted value. I'm not sure if variables are mutable in php.

Comment: Your output is saying the string length is 18 characters long but you are showing only 3. You should check that first.  Also try using the intval function instead of casting.

Comment: @phiterFernandes I've created a new variable and passed the integer to it... same output as before...

Comment: please add proper code

Comment: Looks like that the `$sec_id` contains some special non-printable characters (likely '\0'). To debug it show output of `var_dump(unpack('C*', $sec_id));`

Comment: @sg- yeah this is strange too... how can I get more information about that? in PHP I know var_dump as the best function to get variables informations...

Comment: Do as Timurib states or use echo(bin2hex($sec_id)); to get a hex dump

Comment: @sg- ok this is the right direction I got the error on the template creation! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using var_dump(unpack('C*', $sec_id)); got the real output of the passed string, the issue is in the template variable creation.